# How to install eclipse product (without gui, as a service) in arm processor 32 bit based Linux

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I am preparing a eclipse product on windows machine. It simply runs as a service without any ui. I have downloded and installed delta pack. I am able to export product for intel processor  based linux machine but unable to do so on 32 bit arm processor.

Arm processor based machine has limited memory and no display, I just need to have an executable for ARM architecture for the eclipse product.
I tried running the executable product made for linux gtx86 but it did not run on ARM based machine. 
 I tried exporting each plugin as executable jars and using osgi plugin I can have those plugins install and start. But then I do not know as how to make a single entry point (a file which can define the order of installing and starting the jars based upon dependencies).

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to not use an eclipse product for non UI cases. Take a look at [bndtools](http://bndtools.org/). It is an eclipse plugin for OSGi development and also provides command line tools. It allows to define a launch config and create a simple runnable jar with all bundles inside. This should make it very easy to install on arm.

Alternatively take a look at [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org). You can define features for your deployments and start them in the karaf container. Karaf is known to work well on ARM based computers like Raspberry PI. See also my [tutorials for karaf](http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/Karaf+Tutorials).

Both approaches have in common that they do not use the Eclipse PDE (which is a major pain). Instead they use bnd inside the build to create bundles.

Answer (score 0):

donwload proper one from this link : https://eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux

Comment: I have edited my question. Please have a look. Eclipse can not be installed and used on my ARM machine, it do not have a display. I connect it via. putty.

Comment: Not to use eclipse seems a better solution. But anyway, you can find similar mechanism with linux. On linux, you can enable display transport on your server, connect with ssh -X, so the display can be sent on your local machine(monitor). Probably, windows has similar feature. You can check PsExec with -X feature.